# Prove that if $x \in R,$ then there exists $n \in Z$ satisfying $x \leq n < x+1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So this question in my book looks like it's essentially asking me to prove the ceiling function exists.

This question is slightly different to other things I found in related question because we're asked to prove the existence of the value in the middle of the inequality.

My initial thoughts are to define an $n \in N$ such that $n > x$ and $-n < x$

Following from this one can say $-n < x \leq n < x + 1$.

Now here I just lose any sort of direction and instead think of trying another method defining a set and using the properties of $inf$ and $sup$ to move from there. The tricky thing I encounter as a roadblock  is once again the proving of the existence of the $n$ which is different to many related questions.

Any help or solutions are appreciated, ready and rearing to reply :)

Comment: Take the largest $n$ with $n<x$. Then $n+1<x+1$  but on the other hand $n+1$ cannot be smaller than $x$ since $n$ is the largest with that property. Hence $x\leq n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the "well ordering property" of the positive integers- every non-empty set of positive integers contains a smallest member. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle)

Given a real number, x, Let A be the set of all positive integers strictly greater than x.  By the "Archimedian property" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) that set is non-empty.  Let m be the smallest member of that set.

Let n= m- 1.  Then n< m and since m is the **smallest** member of A, n is not in A.  Therefore, $n\le x$.  But n+ 1= m which **is** in A.  n+ 1> x

Comment: Ah that's intuitive, is it correct to say that if $n+1 > x$ than $n < x + 1$ is true because $m - 1$ is not a number strictly greater than $x$? I know that sounds almost silly to read out but I'm just trying to conceptualise the inequality on top of seeing it algebraically true. Thank you. @user247327

Comment: You have already that $n\le x$.  Adding 1 to the right side but not the left side just makes the right side still larger so gives $n< x+ 1$,